# Content going outside of body when zooming even with scrolling enabled

Tags: html, css

I have this code for calendar but when I'm zooming in page top part goes outside of `body` and i cant even scroll up to see it

Normally everything looks fine like in this picture

[image]

But when i zoom in to 200% i get this for example

[image]

If I keep zooming picture goes out of view completely. How can I fix this and is there anything im doing wrong?

```
<div style="width: 100%; max-width: 700px; position: absolute; top:50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); margin: auto;">

<div class="calendar">
    <div class="calendar__picture">
        
    </div>
    <div class="grid-container" id="grid_container">

        <div class="grid-item-number">22</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">23</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">24</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">25</div>  
        <div class="grid-item-number">26</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">27</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">28</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">29</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">30</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">31</div>

        <div class="grid-item-number">22</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">23</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">24</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">25</div>  
        <div class="grid-item-number">26</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">27</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">28</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">29</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">30</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">31</div>

        <div class="grid-item-number">22</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">23</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">24</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">25</div>  
        <div class="grid-item-number">26</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">27</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">28</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">29</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">30</div>
        <div class="grid-item-number">31</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

and here are CSS

```
  .calendar {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 50px rgba(#000, 0.5);
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .calendar__picture {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    
    color: #fff;
    background: url("/static/serviss.png") 70% 100%/ 700px 273px no-repeat fixed;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(#000, 0.2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    padding: 10px;
  }

 .grid-item-number {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(175, 175, 175, 0.8);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;

    position: relative;
    
    width : 95%;
    
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have `overflow: hidden` on `.calendar`. That would remove the ability to scroll that element. If you want that element to be scrollable, you would have to use `overflow: auto`.

If, however, you only want the body to be scrollable, and not the calendar itself, you have to change your CSS a bit.

1. It is not a good practice to put lots of CSS in the element's `style` attribute. Keep CSS in .css files, and HTML in .html files!
2. You are positioning your whole thing on the dead center of the body. If the element becomes too big, it will be cut off at the top or left portion, and will not be able to be scrolled to, as the scrolling can only go down or right.  All the things that exceed the DOM's left and top boundaries will be always cut off.

So, possible solution: try using flexbox or grid to center your calendar. You would use:

```html
<div class="calendar-wrapper">
    <div class="calendar">
        <div class="calendar__picture"></div>
        <div class="grid-container" id="grid_container">
            <!-- rest of code -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.calendar-wrapper {
    display: flex; /* or grid */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

This will center the calendar contents. However, it won't be on the center of the screen, but wherever the DOM puts it. To center it on the whole screen, you could add `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;`, assuming the body already covers the whole screen.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ty for ur answer man. I did this but now i dont see image unless i scroll all the way in, then it comes out of somewhere. Also calendar is at the left side on screen. But yea mostly wonder why i cant see picture now. Probably something with `position` attribute?

Comment: If anyone is reading this I would suggest learning about `display: grid`. That might be the best way to approach positioning of elements. Grid combined with measurements such as `100vh` `100vw` `height: auto;` really saved the day